# Can a Thread not be daemonized in python3.2?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.2

I am running a script in **python-3.2** on a **Raspberry Pi  2 Model B**

The thread looks like this:

```
myThread = threading.Thread(target=someFunction, args=(arg1,arg2,arg3),
           daemon=True)
myThread.start()
```

Everytime this thread gets called. this *error* gets triggered:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'daemon'
```

I know that there is not **Python-3.4** stable version for the **Debian Wheezy Version 7.10** hence I have to work around with **python 3.2**

Ironically, the [Python 3.2 Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.daemon) does state that `daemon` is a boolean available.

What is this glitch and how can I solve this?

Comment: That documentation is describing _attributes_, not arguments. Just assign to `daemon` before you call `start`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The daemon argument was added in version 3.3, [see](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread). Setting the flag in prior versions works like this:

```
myThread = threading.Thread(target=someFunction, args=(arg1,arg2,arg3))
myThread.daemon = True
myThread.start()
```

Comment: will this also work for __python 3.4__ ? I am just curious in terms of compatibility since most of my code is based on 3.4